# Is there a good resource for creating Node.js documentation with YUIdoc?

Tags: node.js, yuidoc

I'm having a hard time understanding how I should document my Node API using YUIdoc.

I have so many "seemingly simple" questions. How do I differentiate "Routes" from "Models"? At the moment I'm using "route.foo" and "model.foo" but that doesn't feel right at all.